# React.js run function on bootstraping

Tags: reactjs, interceptor, bearer-token

I can't find a way to fun a function once the app bootstraps it self. I am using bearer token authentication and if the user has logged in before the token is stored in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.body.access_token);
```

Then I am using interceptors to add a constant header to every request

```
    authorizationInterceptor: {
    enable: () => {
        if(auth.loggedIn())
        {
            fetchIntercept.register({
                request: function (url, config) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken();
                    return [url, config];
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I am running the `authorizationInterceptor.enable()` on login request, but if the user already has logged in and hits refresh I need to run the interceptor again. So is there a way to run a function once only after app bootstrapping is finished? I do not want to add a check in every fetch request, seems very redundant.

Comment: Are you looking for [`componentDidMount()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)?

Comment: This needs to apply to the whole application and not a single component :) If I would use componentDidMount(), then I would still have to add the check to each component :)

Comment: Don't you have a container component like `<App />` that is always present? You can pass a value down or invoke an action when `componentDidMount()` called in `<App />`.

Comment: Thanks mate :) forgot I had that place.